# failed to determine the setup path of the list schema {22A9EF51-737B-4FF2-9346-694633FE4416}, list template 850

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

We have SharePoint 2010 farm and were having issues in ConfigDB. So i created new Config DB via PowerShell command, created new central admin site.
Then i created a new web application and while creation of web app, i entered the name of existing/old ContentDB (of older web app, as i want to attach existing contentDB with new app). When i browse the web app, i am getting following error.

[image]

When i open http://localhost:1234/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx , it is showing content well but when i click on "pages", it is giving error, and in ULS logs, it is giving following error.

failed to determine the setup path of the list schema {22A9EF51-737B-4FF2-9346-694633FE4416}, list template 850.

[image]

kindly guide. thanks

Comment: First thing that comes to my mind - you might need to redeploy/reactivate any custom features/solutions deployed.

Comment: You need Test-SPContentDatabase and you will see all errors set NewWebApplication configuration old ContentDB.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enable SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature in the site settings?

From the error message, "list template 850" is Page library template, and the Pages library created automatically when we enable publishing feature.

Can you access site settings page( http://sp/_layouts/15/settings.aspx )?

If so, enable “SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure” feature via Site collection feature and activate “SharePoint Server Publishing” via Mange site features.